# How to search any where from table using Python and Sqlite3?

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I need to search from any where from table using Python and sqlite3. I need to change my query. My code is below:

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?")
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Name LIKE '%s%';" % name,)
```

Here actually I need to implement the `LIKE` query and also in same format as written above.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You can just replace the `=` with `LIKE` and that will work. Do you want to be able to search any field?

Comment: I need to search by using any charcter means if input will only `s` ,the name containing `s` anywhere will be fetched.

Comment: The query itself needs to be `WHERE Name LIKE '%s%'`, but make sure you use parameter binding, so you don't expose your app to SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @halfer after adding your stuff its throwing the error `i.e-not enough arguments for format string`

Comment: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44617051/what-is-this-cur-execute-statement-doing) - it looks like you can use `WHERE Name LIKE ?` and then supply `name` after a comma. You have a `%` between the two args presently.

Comment: i used comma still same error.

Comment: OK, update your question with the code you now have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149693/discussion-between-satya-and-halfer).

Comment: Come on, make an effort. The method `cur.execute()` takes two parameters, and parameters are always separated with a comma. I don't know Python, but the other question suggests the second parameter should be `( name )` i.e. surrounded with round brackets. No time to chat.

Comment: Edit the question to show the code you're actually using, and the problem you have with it.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45212942/getting-typeerror-while-fetching-value-from-table-using-python-and-django), you should pass the value tuple as the second argument:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM User WHERE Name LIKE %s", (name,))
```