# Getting TypeError while fetching value from table using Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I am getting error while fetching value from table using Python and Django. The error is below:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

My code is below:

```
rname = request.POST.get('rname')
keyword = '%' + rname + '%'
 all_value = Meeting.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM booking_meeting WHERE room_name LIKE ? ", (keyword,))
```

Here I am getting the error.

Comment: Why are you doing this with `.raw`? It's simple as a standard ORM query, using `__contains`.

Comment: I need to implement the sql query,its my requirement.

Comment: No, you don't. Your requirement is "do a LIKE query on 'rname'". And the way to implement it is `Meeting.objects.filter(room_name__icontains=rname)`.

Comment: Any way I need to know how can I remove this error in this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `%s` as the placeholder instead of `?`:

```
all_value = Meeting.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM booking_meeting WHERE room_name LIKE %s ", (keyword,))
```

See the documentation at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#connections-and-cursors:

> Also note that Django expects the "%s" placeholder, not the "?" placeholder, which is used by the SQLite Python bindings. This is for the sake of consistency and sanity.